# How to add a MTL texture to an OBJ in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Hello so I am trying to figure out how to add an MTL file to my OBJ in three.js. I had my OBJ loaded and was coming back to fix this issue. Now when I added the code for the MTL file to be loaded using `MTLLoader` it is not getting passed `mtlLoader.load(url, ....)` (as in after adding this bit of code now only the scene is being rendered with nothing inside of it). I am using alerts to track the progress of the code and am getting alerts from before this statement but not after. All of the solutions I have found include using `OBJMTLLoader` which is no longer part of the current version of three.js (r74).

Comment: Not sure why OBJMTLLoader was removed from the r74 examples, but there is nothing stopping you from taking a look how it used MTLLoader to load the texture, Just take a [look at the source here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r73/examples/js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js). Or maybe even still using the OBJMTLLoader class if it still works in r74

Comment: [Here is the commit](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/ad41d295eeb6cb77cb56e931fea881fe71fcb6ab#diff-12ac5f8fb38da21d5a5eaa89ee22f155) that removed OBJMTLLoader and [here is the issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7524)

Answer (score 15):

This code is taken from the official example of loading an obj + mtl:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( 'obj/male02/' );
mtlLoader.setPath( 'obj/male02/' );
var url = "male02_dds.mtl";
mtlLoader.load( url, function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( 'obj/male02/' );
    objLoader.load( 'male02.obj', function ( object ) {

        object.position.y = - 95;
        scene.add( object );

    }, onProgress, onError );

});
```

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj_mtl

You assign the materials to the OBJ now via:

`objLoader.setMaterials( materials );`

If you want to manipulate the materials, what the `mtlLoader` is giving you in the callback is an instance of `THREE.MTLLoader.MaterialCreator`. So you can get the materials with `materials.getAsArray()` for example. See the source for all possible functions: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js#L138-L417

Comment: I am currently trying to implement this code. I had tried it before posting here, but my issue still exists. I have put an alert statement to see if an MTLLoader is being created (it is), however I put an alert ststement on the line directly after `mtlLoader.load( url, function( materials ) {` but it never reaches this statement.

Comment: It is necessary to set the base Url and Path and then calling the loader with *only* the model name. Maybe there is an issue with your mtl file, you could try loading the model + mtl file that is shipped with three.js using your code and see what happens.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my mtl, I have opened it in multiple 3D model viewers and it is fine in all of them.

Comment: So I am getting an error saying that `loader.setPath is not a function`?

Comment: Would love to see an explanation of what each of the lines does.